# What happens if you missconfigure a feedforwardnetwork as "feedforward = false"

Tags: python, neat, feed-forward

In Python NEAT you can create Feedforward-Networks or Recurrent-Networks, but you can also configure the binary setting for Feedforward in the config-file.

Now i'm uncertain what a Feedforward network with disabled feedforward would process.

If "Feedforward = True" in the config, recurrent Connections can(but dont have to) be made. In the code you can still refere to it as nn.FeedforwardNetwork
Since i cant find documentation on the matter. My Hypothesis is that recurrent connections can be made but can't be processed by the network. Can s.o confirm that?

So, py-File:

```py
net = neat.nn.RecurrentNetwork.create(genome, config)
```

and config.txt:

```
feed_forward                 = True
```

If s.o could clear that up, that would be very helpfull.